# Webpack image loader Error

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm having trouble trying to import images to my project receiving this error when bulding: Module parse failed: C:\Users\Angelo\OptaService\OptaService\images\ImageTest.png Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

This is my webpack configuration:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {test: /\.(js)$/, use: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/},
        {test: /\.css$/, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']},

    ],
    loaders: [ {
        test: /\.js|.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
    }, {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        loaders: [
            'file?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
            'image-webpack?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false'
        ]
    } ]
},
```

I've already npm installed image-webpack-loader and file-loader.
Also i'm importing the images in the component like this:

```
import image from './../../images/ImageTest.png';
```

...

```
<img className="img-fluid" src={image} alt="OptaService Logo"/>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This is the way I would set up your webpack config, you are mixing loaders and rules, you can check out the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/) to investigate a little further how to setup your config properly.

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js|.jsx?$/,
      use: 'babel-loader',
      exclude: /node_modules/
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
    },
    {
      test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
      loaders: [
        'file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
        'image-webpack-loader?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false'
       ]
    }
  ]
},
```

Answer (score 1):

That would be better to set up your Webpack config file to support different file types in production and development separately with maximum support for all files. To do so I recommend having 3 files for your Webpack config in the root of your project.

1. webpack.common.js for common settings between production and development
2. webpack.prod.js for production
3. webpack.dev.js for development

**webpack.common.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/App.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].[hash].css',
      chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].css'
    })
  ],
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
              localIdentName: '[local]--[hash:base64:5]',
              sourceMap: true
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif|pdf)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[ext]'
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

**webpack.prod.js**

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');
module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'production',
});
```

**webpack.dev.js**

```
const path = require("path");
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    port: 8181,
    open: 'google chrome',
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
});
```

with these 3 config files, you need 'dist' and 'src' directories at the root of your project.